# Entity Framework 6 db first creates entities differently on dev machines

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Really weird one, EF 6.1.3, database first approach, pluralize naming unchecked, my scenario - I have 2 tables for the sake of an example:

Company:

```
Id,Name,CreatedBy(FK->User.Id),CreatedDate,ModifiedBy(FK->User.Id),ModifiedDate
```

User:

```
Id,Name,CompanyId(FK->Company.Id(nullable))
```

When I update the edmx from the DB, my User entity (simplified for the sake of this example) has a Company property e.g. virtual Company Company, and a hashset of type Company called Company1. The issue is that when another DEV in my team updates the edmx using the same schema as me, it seems that the ordering of the entity's properties generated are slightly different on his machine and his User entity has company property called Company1 and a hashset of company called Company. This causes our branch to break, we are both using EF 6.1.3, SQL 2014, VS2015 sp3, .net 4.6.

At first we thought that there might be a mismatch in foreign keys in both of our local DB, but I took a db backup from the other DEV and ran an update of the edmx and this still did not help. I did install a sp for SQL 2014 which helped to speed up edmx generation few months back and I havent asked the other DEV if he had installed it but for the time being Im giving the benefit of the doubt to MS that that update wouldn't break every code base out there using DB first EF....

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Check column order for differences.

Comment: Hi @zaitsman, I used a DB backup from the other DEV as well, same issues - I dont think this is a database issue, might be a SQL server or EF issue.